# Adding a new section in Mezzanine CMS (Django) admin

Tags: django, mezzanine

I'm totally new to Mezzanine CMS. I got handed a site to work with and so far I've been able to do all the changes without problem. I've run across a problem in which they want a new section in the home page. I go to the admin section to edit the home page, but there is no extra content field.

On the home page, I see 4 sections "content" "priorities" "testimonials" and "clients". I would like to have another "content" area as a 5th section. How do I go on and add this section? I'm totally new to Django but would be appreciative if someone could explain or point in the right direction.

Here is a link to an image for reference. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgC7m.jpg
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The homepage content would be backed by a Django model with attributes for the partners and testimonial fields. You'll need to find the Python class for this model in your code base (you could search for those field names), and you'll need to add a new attribute for the new section you need.

Django and Mezzanine have lots of different field types you can use for these attributes, so consult their respective documentation for how those work (Django's are a lot more comprehensive, so start there).

Once you've done that, you'll need to create a database migration for the new attribute - that adds the field to the database table that will store the actual content, again consult the Django documentation for how these work.

Finally you may need to add the new field to the Admin class, which is the Python class (similar to the model) that controls which fields appear in the admin interface, and how they appear. I say "may" as these generally appear automatically without any code, but if things have been modified to a certain extent, you may need to do this manually.